# How can I make vim tag jumps as smart as OmniCppComplete?

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags, omnicppcomplete

I generate my tags (Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310) like this:

```
 ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -L ctags.files
```

I have roughly this class structure:

```
class RenderObject
{
    InterpolatedVector offset;
};

class Quad : public RenderObject
{
};

class KeyframeWidget : public Quad
{
    void shiftRight()
    {
        if (!offset.isInterpolating())
            offset.interpolateTo(Vector(offset.x+80, 0), 0.1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

(Code is from [Aquaria's open source release](http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/06/Aquaria-goes-open-source).)

If I tag jump on `offset` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>), then I get a list every `offset` in my codebase. After I type `offset.` to the end of `shiftRight()`, OmniCppComplete starts offering completions only for `InterpolatedVector`.

How can I make my tag jumps as smart as [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520)?

Is it just that tag jumps don't use any context, so they only know symbol names? (Is it the exact same as `:tag <C-r><C-w><CR>`?) Is there a vim alternative that makes them context-aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently started using the SmartTag plugin for Vim & find it very good at using contextual information from the surrounding C++ code to find the right tag.

You can download it here:

https://github.com/MarcWeber/SmartTag

To be able to use it with Ctrl-] you will need to use a Vim release with the tagfunc
patch applied. It's here:

http://llorens.visualserver.org/vim73-tagfunc.zip