# Vim and ctags - select appropriate tag

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm using ctags plugin in vim. And I have one annoying problem - when I want to jump to member function definition some functions/methods that have duplicate names are listed in a list of tags I could jump.

What's even more ridiculous - most of these tags don't even closely match signature and even class!

How can this be so dumb? How can it not figure out that I want to jump to symbol definition: with same class and same signature.

If there's no plugin to do it, how can I alter vim (preferrably with script) do select members while comparing signatures and classes? Or do I have to dig into the vim code itself to do it?

I'll put up a screenshot so that people would understand what I'm talking about

[image: screenshot]

It's ridiculous, it put up all the tags where member has name "run" and it doesn't even care checking for the same class and signature, as it would completely eliminate this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the pesimistic answers - there's a solution. A Vim plugin that takes care of the EXACT problem I've faced - a SmartTag plugin.

https://github.com/MarcWeber/SmartTag

However, it doesn't work out of the box since you need to patch vim so you could replace tagfunc (function that is responsible for tag jumping and changing behaviour of vim tag mechanism)

So, I patched newest vim sources with this patch:

[Discussion board](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/nq4zuT-lCIQ/DTGZsdkyBfsJ) -> Patch number four ( [Download patch](https://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/attach/204099e54067d248/tagfunc.patch.4?part=2) )

I've patched vim 7.4 source, compiled it, installed it and added one line to .vimrc

set tagfunc=SmartTag#SmartTagFunc

That's it!!! Vim no longer jumps to dumb tags! Now it differentiates according to class and scope.

I have no idea why this plugin is so unpopular - it's a LIFESAVER!

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272458/how-can-i-make-vim-tag-jumps-as-smart-as-omnicppcomplete)

Answer (score 6):

Your expectations are both too high *and* misguided because **neither Vim nor ctags understand your code like an IDE would.**

There is *no* built-in way to make Vim list only "relevant" tags because:

- it doesn't know what's "relevant" to you,
- it lists all the matching tags in order of appearance in your `tags` file *starting with those from the current file.*

You could probably write a function to use instead of `:tjump` and friends that would do the magic you are asking for, though, but I don't think it would be a trivial endeavour.

There are, however, [many "better" alternatives to ctags](https://github.com/ffevotte/clang-tags#similar-tools) and [then some.](https://github.com/exclipy/clang_indexer) You should try them.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a very elegant solution, but you COULD install Eclipse and its C/C++ development tools, and then use eclim (http://eclim.org) to let Eclipse do the heavy work with Vim as the front-end. That works fairly well for me with C code. I've also use cscope only for C code, but that may also be able to provide "smarter" tag recognition. ctags is powerful but pretty dumb.